# Initialize an Eigen::Vector from different segments of a single array

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, armadillo

I have to construct an `Eigen::Vector` from an array by selecting some of its members. I know that I can use `Eigen::Map` to initialize an `Eigen::Vector` without copying.

Suppose I have an array of `N` integers and I need to make an `Eigen::VectorXi` by selecting the array values having indexes from `j` to `j+m` and `k` to `k+m` without copying the values.

Is this somehow possible in Eigen or Armadillo?

Example:

```
 int array[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
 //I need to initialize a Eigen::VectorXi with values having 0 to 0+3   
 // indices and 5 to 5+3 indices. ie with elements {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9}
```

Comment: Suppose you had some code, and a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

You can join two vectors, each generated with `Map`, by using the [commma initializer](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html#title0):

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int m = 4;
int j = 0, k = 5;
VectorXi w(2*m);
w << Map<VectorXi>(&array[j], m) , Map<VectorXi>(&array[k], m);
```

Note that `w` must be initialized with its size to prevent assertion failures.

Answer (score 2):

With Armadillo you can use the [advanced constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) for vectors, followed by the [join_cols() / join_rows()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#join) functions:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

Col<int> A( &array[0], 4, false );
Col<int> B( &array[5], 4, false );

Col<int> C = join_cols(A,B);
```

[Col<>](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) is the Armadillo template class for column vectors.  Change `Col<int>` to `Row<int>` if you need row vectors.

Comment: But, in `join_cols()` both `A` and `B` are copied.

Comment: @user294664 - Yes, but copying is a cheap operation. To properly handle non-contiguous memory chunks would make the underlying container classes rather complex and probably slow, which would defeat the purpose of avoiding copies.